# How to stop sticky nav from preventing scrolling to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the mobile version of the site, the sticky `nav` appears after you scroll past the header, however once this appears, you can't scroll back up to the very top of the page because the `nav` won't unstick. What do I need to change to allow me to scroll to the top of the page?

```
$(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-small .genesis-nav-

    // Sticky Navigation
    var headerHeight = $('.site-header').innerHeight();
    var beforeheaderHeight = $('.before-header').outerHeight();
    var abovenavHeight = headerHeight + beforeheaderHeight - 1;

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ($(document).scrollTop() > abovenavHeight){
      $('.navigation-container').addClass('fixed');
            $('.nav-primary').addClass('fixed');
                        $('.nav-secondary').addClass('fixed');

        } else {
      $('.navigation-container').removeClass('fixed');
            $('.nav-primary').removeClass('fixed');
            $('.nav-secondary').removeClass('fixed');

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) instead of JS to do your sticky menu.